# Facebook Login not working after ADColony framework added in iOS Application?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook, adcolony

In my application feature for Social media login using Facebook working properly.

But after adding AdColony in app.

Facebook login not working. Below code for Facebook login

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
login.loginBehavior=FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount;

[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email",@"public_profile",@"user_friends"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Process error %@",result);

    }
    else if (result.isCancelled)
        }
    else {

    }
 }];
```

Every time i return back with result.isCancelled YES.

i refer this link for compatibility but didn't got any solution 
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/762583/facebook-sdk-and-adcolony-compatible-in-ios.html

So what can I do ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are there any log messages in Xcode console when you try to show facebook dialog?